# Partial isometry, Isometry and Gram matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, isometry

Suppose I have a set of matrices $\mathcal{H}$ s.t. $\forall H\in\mathcal{H}, \ H = CU$ where $C$ is a fixed matrix and $U$ is an orthonormal matrix. We know that this set can be characterized completely by the Gram matrix, i.e. given any set of matrices ${H_1, \ldots, H_n}$ we can check if $H_i \in \mathcal{H}$ by calculating $G_i = H_i H^{\dagger}_i$ and check whether $G_i = C^2$.
Now, suppose that given $H_1, H_2$ we want to check whether there exists a partial isometry such that $H_1 U_1 = H_2 U_2$ where $U_i = W_i S_r V^{\dagger}_i$ with $W_i, V_i$ orthonormal and $S_r = diag(I_{r\times r},0_{n-r \times n-r})$. Assuming that $r$ is known, is there any simple way to verify such a relation?

Answer (score 1):

$H_1 = CW_1$ and $H_2 = CW_2$,$\implies H_1W_1^TW_2 = H_2 $. So $W_1^TW_2$ is your partial isometry. So any two matrix can be related in the way you mentioned ?

Good luck !

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am not sure that this translation is clear to me since as I see it partial isometries don't necessarily have to be invertible? Anyway, although the intuition for such matrices is clear to me I am not sure I am familiar with the algebraic argument which describes them. Thanks!

Comment: Orthonormal matrices are invertible. The argument  works even if the matrix $U$ is rectangular with orthonormal rows. May be edit the question on dimensions of the matrices you want?

Comment: Since the matrix $S_r$ has only r non-zero elements on its diagonal the partial isometry can be non-invertible (for example, it can be the matrix $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Since $W_1$ and $W_2$ in my answer is orthonormal, they are invertible. So i wrote. when you say $H = CU$, what exactly is the $U$ matrix ? you are referring it as orthonormal which would mean invertible without reference to the dimension of this matrix $U$. A matrix $U$ is orthonormal iff $U^{-1} = U^T$.